# Facebook Connect Replaced?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I would like to develop an IOs app with facebook integrated. 
However, after some research I found out that facebook connect seem to be outdated?
Even the facebook official page only talk about Single Sign On where user will be redirect away the app to login.

So my question is, do you think it's still safe to use Facebook Connect?
Since i still see a lot app using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Facebook connect for iOS has been replaced with [Facebook SDK for iOS](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) and it is an open source library on Github that users their Graph API.  I would not start a new project with the deprecated Facebook connect library because it will eventually be killed and they won't give you a lot of notice since the replacement has already been out for over a year.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I decided to implement the latest Facebook SDK. However i'm confused with the use of it and am currently trying to implement it. Would be great if you could direct me some link beside the Facebook official documentation. Thank you!

Comment: The github link has a sample project that includes authentication and making sample api calls.  All you need to do is open it and change the keys.